# Windows 7 Laptop keeps entering sleep mode even though power settings state never

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop

I have all my power option settings set at never, sleep, hibernate, dim monitor.  However when I step away from my laptop, it enters sleep mode.  What else can I do?  Running Windows 7 on a Toshiba Satellite Lap Top.

Answer (score 1):

Toshiba most likely has it's own setting to do this. If so there is software installed from Toshiba that is forcing it into this mode. To fix this you must find the software and change the settings. I suggest searching your computer for something along the lines of "Toshiba Battery Saver".