# Windows 8 Notebook doesn't stay awake, unable to turn off Sleep Mode

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, power-management

I have an ASUS Pro64JQ notebook, running Windows 8 Pro (64-bit).
Recently I noticed that it automatically goes to sleep mode after 5 minutes,
even when I turn sleep mode off in the power management settings.

I don't have any third party power management applications installed, so that can't be the problem.

What could be causing this problem, and how can I solve it? Thanks!

---

See [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39714652/PowerScheme.txt) file, which gives you all the information about my power scheme. (sorry for the dutch words)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 Goes to Sleep in conflict with Power Option Setting](http://superuser.com/questions/124772/windows-7-goes-to-sleep-in-conflict-with-power-option-setting) also [Windows 7 Laptop keeps entering sleep mode even though power settings state never](http://superuser.com/questions/553454/windows-7-laptop-keeps-entering-sleep-mode-even-though-power-settings-state-neve?lq=1)

Comment: I don't have ASUS power management software installed, and I double checked the advanced options, so those 'duplicates' do not help me :(